# Is it possible to create nested classes in PHP as it is in C#?

Tags: c#, php, oop

In C# you can have **nested** classes like this, which are useful if you have classes which do not have meaning **outside the scope** of one particular class, e.g. in a **factory** pattern:

```
public abstract class BankAccount
{
  private BankAccount() {} 
  private sealed class SavingsAccount : BankAccount { ... }
  private sealed class CheckingAccount : BankAccount { ... }
  public BankAccount MakeSavingAccount() { ... }
  public BankAccount MakeCheckingAccount() { ... }
}
```

Is this possible in PHP?

I've read that it was planned for PHP 5, then cancelled, then planned again, but can't find definitive info.

**Does anyone know how to create nested classes (classes within the scope of another class) as in the above C# example using PHP 5.3?**

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible in PHP. Classes must inhabit the global namespace; the best you can do is just pretend they don't exist in all of your other code.

This kind of thing is common in PHP; for example, PHP lacks static initializers, so if you want to eagerly initialize the static members of a class, it must be done by calling a public method from outside the class. Ugly.